# Get widget at point

Tags: widget

For example, I inserted many `link` widgets like this:

```
(widget-create `(link :tag "Test link"
                      :button-prefix ""
                      :button-suffix ""
                      :button-face nil
                      :format "%[%t\n%]"
                      :help-echo ""
                      :action nil
                      'test))
```

Later I want to retrieve a specific link widget at point to modify some of its values, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
(get-char-property (point) 'button)
```

And I will get the widget of type `'button` at point. `link` is also a widget of `'button` type.